# Unity/C# - Existing API for applying 3D rotations?

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry

I want to proceduraly generate meshes. I created a method to supply the vertices of a circle. The idea is that it creates a shape in 2d and then rotates it in 3d assuming that "rotation" is the vector of the shapes normal axis.

```
 public List<Vector3> Loop (Vector3 center, Vector3 rotation, float radius, int divisions)
 {
     List<Vector3> loop = new List<Vector3>();
     for(int p = 0; p < divisions; p++)
     {
         float u = (float)Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * p / divisions) * radius;
         float v = (float)Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * p / divisions) * radius;
         float x = 0;
         float y = 0;
         float z = 0;
         // Apply rotation to u & v to get x, y, z
         loop.Add(new Vector3(x, y, z));
     }
     return loop;
 }
```

Creating the circle in 2d (u & v) was super easy but when I looked into applying 3d rotations, it seemed to be a complete rabbit hole completely beyond my comprehension.

Is there a way to use existing API to do this?

Comment: you can also very simply use `RotateAround` .. enjoy !

Comment: @Fattie Asker doesn't have input to use as an axis or angle. Would you like to help them convert their circle normal vector (they name it `rotation`) to the axis & angle to use in `RotateAround`?

Answer (score 1):

I would pass in an axis parameter that you are rotating `rotation` around, then use Cross products to find the "up" direction for the "forward" that is the normal of the circle.

Use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html), then `Quaternion * Vector3` to apply the rotation to the position:

```
public List<Vector3> Loop (Vector3 center, Vector3 rotation, Vector3 axis, float radius, int divisions)
 {
     List<Vector3> loop = new List<Vector3>();
     for(int p = 0; p < divisions; p++)
     {
         float u = (float)Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * p / divisions) * radius;
         float v = (float)Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * p / divisions) * radius;
         Vector3 fromPosition = new Vector3(u, v, 0f);

         Vector3 up = Vector3.Cross(rotation.normalized, axis.normalized);

         Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(rotation, up);
         loop.Add(rot * fromPosition);
     }
     return loop;
 }
```

So you could do something like: `List<Vector3> res = Loop(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, Vector3.right, 10f, 20);`

Comment: Quaternions are a bit dangerous for someone new to Unity!  What about simply https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

Comment: @Fattie Sure, you can use that if you can convert the normal of the desired circle (`rotation`) to an axis and an angle.

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks for help. On the most part this seems to work. But there's some weird thing where it reaches 180 degreed and it flips around or something. I created a mesh that adds a ring of verts at regular intervals along a helix and fills in the triangles; its all smooth except for 1 span per revolution where all the triangles stretch over to the other side.

Comment: @LorryLaurencemcLarry , hi, be sure to  read THIS  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8427705/294884 and especially the Famous Article linked from there !!

Comment: @LorryLaurencemcLarry That's because it doesn't know what axis to rotate around, so it can guess wrong at 180 degrees. If you give an axis, you can use cross products and `LookRotation`